# USB-Battery load sharing circuit comparison

Tags: circuit-design, circuit-protection, load

I have found two different load-sharing circuits on Adafruit modules:

[image: Comparison of load-sharing circuits]

The 32u4 (left) only employs a schottky diode, while the nRF52 (right) uses an additional pull-down resistor as well as a transistor.

Since the 32u4 design is simpler, what are its drawbacks?
Does it also allow having VBUS and VBAT connected, or can VBAT damage VBUS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hm, what happens if VBAT > VBUS in the left case?

Comment: I am not really sure, but I assume something bad since you're asking. I guess that situation is ruled out at design decision because the intended use is VBUS to be 5V from a USB and VBAT a single-cell LiPo batter (4.2V maximum). 
Would adding another diode on the VBUS help on preventing any problems in the VBAT > VBUS case?

Comment: @MarcusMüller these are all designed for 3.7V 1 cell Lipo, so minimal risk of that.

Answer (score 3):

The nRF52 uses a more efficient system for running off of battery, since the transistor will have almost no voltage/power drop, where as the diode on the 32u4 will always drop 0.25V.

While this does not matter for power efficiency since your linear regulator will waste the power regardless, it does allow the nRF52 to operate at a lower battery voltage, since there is not an additional 0.25v drop infront of the regulator.

In summary (Rough Numbers due to load dependent):
The 32u4 will stop regulating at a Vbat ~ 3.65
The nRF52 will stop regulating at a Vbat ~ 3.4

All things the same, the nRF52 board will be able to fully drain the last ~10% out of a Lipo battery, while keeping a well regulated 3.3V line the whole time.